# Load local web files & resources in WKWebView

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, webkit, wkwebview

Unlike with UIWebView and previous versions of WKWebView (iOS 10 & macOS 10.12), the default load operation for local files has moved from `Bundle.main.path` to `Bundle.main.url`. Similarly, `loadFileURL` has also become the default function to load local resources in WKWebView.

I know that `.path` and `.url` are entirely different and have both worked in the past – `.path` historically being the default-chosen method; however, it seems that the latest versions of Swift have broken most, if not all, `.path` solutions. The `.path` solutions seem to now *flatten* the directory hierarchy, putting all of the CSS, JS, and any other sub-directory contents, into one big directory. This causes loading errors when WKWebView attempts to load index.html, for example, with a linked, sub-folder stylesheet (ie. `/css/style.css`).

After seeing numerous questions and countless uncertain/broken answers to match, is there a quick and painless solution for implementing a WKWebView that can load local resources (including linked CSS/JS files), without any workarounds?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

*Updated for Swift 4, Xcode 9.3*

---

This methods allows WKWebView to properly read your hierarchy of directories and sub-directories for linked CSS, JS and most other files. You do **NOT** need to change your HTML, CSS or JS code.

## Solution (Quick)

1. Add the web folder to your project (File > Add Files to Project)

   - Copy items if needed
   - Create folder references *
   - Add to targets (that are applicable)
2. Add the following code to the `viewDidLoad` and personalize it to your needs:

   ```
   let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "website")!
   webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
   let request = URLRequest(url: url)
   webView.load(request)
   ```

---

## Solution (In-Depth)

### Step 1

Import the folder of local web files anywhere into your project. Make sure that you:

[image: Xcode > File > Add Files to "Project"]

> ☑️ Copy items if needed
>
> ☑️ **Create folder references** *(not "Create groups")*
>
> ☑️ Add to targets

### Step 2

Go to the View Controller with the WKWebView and add the following code to the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "website")!
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
webView.load(request)
```

- `index` – the name of the file to load (without the `.html` extension)
- `website` – the name of your web folder (`index.html` should be at the root of this directory)

### Conclusion

The overall code should look something like this:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "Website")!
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }

}
```

If any of you have further questions about this method or the code, I'll do my best to answer!

Comment: Thank you so much. Have been struggling to find a working solution!

Comment: Would this also be the way to wrap a simple HTML5 (including several JS libs) app into a macOS application?

Comment: what is this base url in url request method ??

Comment: Read it twice and remember to: Create folder references (not "Create groups")

Comment: I'm confused why there's a call to `.load(request)` too. I think `loadFileURL()` is the preferred way to load local files, does the `load(request)` do anything extra?

Comment: for what it's worth, I've just spent the last couple of hours trying to get a simple MacOS app to read from a directory - the only way it would do it was through using load(request) and not loadFileURL()

Comment: I get: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. The only way I can get it to work is if I put the index.html in the same folder as the xcodeproj file and use "/" as subdirectory

Comment: For those who couldn't have solved the problem when using WKWebView, **you should add Webkit Library in your Xcode project.** Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048414/wkwebview-is-not-getting-intialized-in-swift-4-xcode-10/54050167#comment98762031_54050167).

Comment: You do not need the call to `load`. Just call `loadFileURL`. The 2nd `load` is pointless.

Comment: In WKWebView to load local file it is taking 10 Sec But in UIwebview it is too quick

Comment: Is there a way to load HTML code, created in memory, maybe held in a string, and passing that directly to the WKWebView?

Comment: The 'Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error occurs when a resource such as png is imported using this method.

Answer (score 15):

This work For Me:

```
        WKWebView *wkwebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        wkwebView.navigationDelegate = self;
        wkwebView.UIDelegate = self;
        [wkwebView.configuration.preferences setValue:@"TRUE" forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:YOURFILEPATH];
        [wkwebView loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:url.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
        [self.view addSubview:wkwebView];
```

Comment: Do I need to do anything in the delegate method? I downloaded a PDF file and saved to the Documents directory. I can preview the PDF file from my Simulator's Documents directory, but the wkWebView shows nothing and not knowing why. Did I miss anything else?

Comment: for pdf file you can use PDFKit

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57428675/8160252

Comment: Really appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue my condition was, I am downloading some 
HTML content from the server and save it to the Document directory and 
show it inside the application. The same controller uses the LIVE URL 
also I have to put the condition with url scheme. **Tested on iOS 13 Xcode 11**

```
  if Url.scheme == "file" as String {
         wkWebView.loadFileURL(Url, allowingReadAccessTo: Url)
    }
    else {
         let request = URLRequest.init(url: Url, cachePolicy:.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval:60)
         wkWebView.load(request)
    }
```

it worked perfect for me

Comment: i have downloaded the images in a local documents directory folder now i have a html string which contains the last path component of img , which are ideally saved in docDirectory , how can i load all the images in that string to wkwebview , can you guide me with steps please.

Comment: in which form did u saved the html content , I have saved all the images separate

Answer (score 2):

1, Open project setting and got to Build Phases tab, open Link Binary with Libraries. Add Webkit framework.

2, Add the html to your project (Copy items if needed)

3, add this to your code:
 @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

4, viewDidLoad
[viewDidLoad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csFA7.png)

Comment: I had to migrate ancient code. Adding Webkit framework was a very helpful hint for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use resources from you project and even shared libraries inside html code with `WKWebView`. 
For instance, I show how to load `pic.png` from bundle that contains `ResourceContainingBundleClassNamed` class.

```
NSSTring * htmlCode = @"<img src='pic.png'>";
NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[ResourceContainingBundleClassNamed class]];
NSURL * base = bundle.resourceURL;
WKWebView * represent = [WKWebView new];
[represent loadHtmlString: htmlCode baseURL: base];
```

The magic is in `resourceURL` bundle property. If you just get path for desired file, then convert it to URL - no success.