# WKWebView is not getting intialized in swift 4 xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, webview, webkit, wkwebview

Could anyone help me in understanding why my webView is not getting initialized here. I am getting the following error because webView is nil.

`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

What exactly I am missing here?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit


class MemoriesViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear( animated )

        let urlString:String = "https://www.apple.com"
        let url:URL = URL(string: urlString)!
        let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)

    }


    }

}
```

Screenshot for better clarity where the error is actually happening:

[image]

Comment: check outlet connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Check if you connect outlet to your webView on storyboard

Comment: The problem was my output was not connected to storyboard

Answer (score 9):

Add Webkit.Frameworks to Linked Framework and Libraries

[image]

You can then add the Outlet for WKWebView and use your code

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class MyWebViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myWV: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let urlString:String = "https://www.apple.com"
    let url:URL = URL(string: urlString)!
    let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    myWV.load(urlRequest)
}


}
```

Comment: You are my life saver. I spent about 2 hours to figure out this problem. **MUST add Webkit.framework**.

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 10, you can foll bellow the step:

1. Click the project
2. Go to **build phase**
3. Go to **Link Binary with Libraries**
4. Click **add plus sing under Link Binary with Libraries**
5. open a windows & search  **Webkit.framework**
6. add & enjoy it
7. Show bellow image
   [image]

Comment: Has this changed? This seems to have become a problem for me since Xcode 10 and Swift 4? Was it linked differently before?

Comment: Count me among the confused. This was never needed prior to XCode 11.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my output was not connected to the storyboard. That's why `@IBOutlet was not getting initialized`.

Comment: what do you mean output? do you mean outlet