# How to use CSS in WKWebView?

Tags: html, css, swift, macos, webkit

I want to use a WKWebView to render a document. I made `Invoice.html` and `Invoice.css` and put them into bundle. When I load Invoice.html to Safari (by dragging file) everything looks OK. But not in WKWebView.
I tried:

**Simple way:**

```
let htmlUrl = URL(fileReferenceLiteralResourceName: "Invoice.html")
let html = String.init(contentsOf: htmlUrl)
webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Beginning of Invoice.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Invoice</title>
        <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="./Invoice.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
            </head>
    <body id="Invoice" xml:lang="en-US">
        <div class="page">
            <div>
                <p>FAKTURA VAT</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>SPRZEDAWCA SELLER: </p>
                </div>
                <p></p>
```

I could see text in `WKWebView` but not styled.

**WKWebView Extension**

```
extension WKWebView {
    func injectCSSFrom(url: URL) {


        let css = try! String(contentsOf: url).split(separator: "\n")
        //let css = "body { background-color : #aabbcc };"
        print (css)
        let js = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(css)'; document.head.appendChild(style);"

        evaluateJavaScript(js) {(result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("DOES NOT WORK", error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

prints :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FA0000;
    font: 7pt "Helvetica";
}

.page {
    width: 21cm;
    height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 1.5cm;
    border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: white;
}
```

Same like by simple way. Nothing, no style, no background color. But if I change `let css = "body { background-color : #aabbcc };"` at least background color changes.

In both cases `evaluate...` throws an error `Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=about:blank, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}`

Is a simple and versatile way to attach `css` to `html` generated locally?

Comment: Answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638653/load-local-web-files-resources-in-wkwebview

Comment: That link doesn't mention the CSS issue in the title