# Cannot load local html file into WKWebView on ios device (not simulator)

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I'm having troubles with the following code. It's supposed to load a local HTML file into a WKWebView.

It works fine on any simulator I've tried (ios 12 / ios 13).

For a reason I do not understand yet, it does not work on device.
Instead, I get a blank screen. Debugging the webview with the Safari debugger shows that the page is "about:blank". It did not load my file... Why ?

Note that I have checked the existence of the file by downloading the app container from the phone and the file is there...

```
- (void)loadIndexConteneurWithHash:(NSString *)hash
{
    NSString *fileName = @"index.html";
    NSString *subpath = hash ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@", fileName, hash] : fileName;
    NSString *rootContainerDirectoryPath = [NSFileUtility pathRelativeToContentDirectoryForSubpath:@"/www/v2"];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:subpath relativeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:rootContainerDirectoryPath]];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0f];

    [self.webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadRequest:) withObject:request waitUntilDone:true];
}
```

Edit: this question is NOT a duplicate of [Load local web files & resources in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638653/load-local-web-files-resources-in-wkwebview)

I do not load my HTML file from the bundle but from the app container as noted originally in my question. I've also tried the `loadFileURL` method and it does not work either.

Comment: What is this `[NSFileUtility pathRelativeToContentDirectoryForSubpath:@"/www/v2"]` method supposed to do ?

Comment: @CZ54 it gives the absolute path for given path relatively to `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<...>/Library/Application Support/<my app id>/LocalContents`

Comment: What delegate method tells? Ok or error?

Comment: @Cy-4AH the `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` is raised and I allow it. But neither the `didFailNavigation` nor the `didFinishNavigation` are called...

Comment: When looking at the duplicate, note that the currently accepted answer shows that you need to call `loadFileURL` and `load`. That 2nd call to `load` is not needed. You just need `loadFileURL`.

Comment: great @rmaddy you've marked that question as a duplicate when I've already looked at the one you've pointed and it does not resolve my problem... I've tried `loadFileURL` and that does not work too... Please un-mark my question, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: The use of `loadFileURL` is what works when loading a local file so it is a duplicate. The use of `loadFileURL` does not require the file to be from the bundle. It works with any local file when used correctly.  As shown in the close message: *"This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question."*. So please post a new question showing your attempt to use `loadFileURL` and clearly provide all relevant details about the URL you attempt to load and any other relevant details.

Answer (score -1):

In order to access a Local ressource you have to use :
`Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyFile", withExtension: "html")`

Comment: It is not a ressource in the bundle, it is a ressource in the app container.

Comment: You mean a file created bu the app itself ? not embbed ?

Comment: yes, I actually unzip a file into the container and try to load the unzipped html file into the WKWebView