# Loading local html with WKWebView

Tags: codenameone

I need to load html/CSS/Javascript files that have been previously downloaded from a server. I can do this on Android and iOS using UIWebView, but fails when enabling WKWebView.

I did some research and seems that there is a workaround to get this working. From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638653/load-local-web-files-resources-in-wkwebview), the solution could be this:

```
 if Url.scheme == "file" as String {
     wkWebView.loadFileURL(Url, allowingReadAccessTo: Url)
}
else {
     let request = URLRequest.init(url: Url, cachePolicy:.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval:60)
     wkWebView.load(request)
}
```

Is this implemented on Codename One? Or there is a better way to get WKWebView working with downloaded html files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implemented in Codename One if you enable `WKWebView` and use a file system storage URL it should work seamlessly see: 
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/iOSPort/nativeSources/IOSNative.m#L2490

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works. There was a mistake in my code, sorry.